# Find a recurrence relation for the number of ternary strings of length n that contain three consecutive zeros.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I've come up with something along the lines of: $$b_n=6b_{n-2}+6b_{n-3}+6b_{n-4}+3^{n-3}, n\ge4$$

I'm not at all sure if this is correct following the ways my teacher has explained in class.

Comment: How did you get that recurrence?

Comment: When you say "contain three consecutive zeros", do you mean contains **at least one** substring 000, or **exactly one**?  Does a string with more than 3 consecutive zeros count?